# Cordova Windows 10/UWP: Remote Mode vs Private Network vs Store Submit

Tags: cordova, uwp

I have developed a Cordova App which is deployed to Windows 10 / UWP platform. Everything works fine, unless I tried to submit the app to the Windows App Store: the Windows App Certification Kit says that I cannot add a ApplicationContentUriRule having WindowsRuntimeAccess to *all* or *allowForWebOnly* indicated in package.windows10.appxmanifest:

```
<uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
   <uap:Rule Match="ms-appx-web:///" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
</uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
```

In some blog entry I read that Cordova and relevant app contents in ms-appx-web context need access to the Windows Runtime.

My app is deployed in remote mode indicated by the web-context in this line in config.xml:

```
<preference name="WindowsDefaultUriPrefix" value="ms-appx-web://" />
```

As stated in the Cordova docs ([see here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html#understanding-remote-mode-vs-local-mode)), when using remote mode, capabilities like enterpriseAuthentication or privateNetworkClientServer are not available. However, I need those capabilities as the app must be able to run in company private networks.

**So my goal is to to deploy an app, that works in remote mode (to use remote resources from the web) and works within private networks at the same time. The deployment must match the restrictions of the Store Certification process.**

What is the recommended way to achieve this? I crawled the web for hours, but found nothing that helped me out.

Thanks for any support!

Comment: The Cordova doc you posted has already offered a work around below: "The network-related restrictions must be worked around by either using an API that doesn't use capability checks or by brokering communication via standard internet communication channels, such as XMLHttpRequest or Web Sockets."

Comment: I have the same problem. do you have the solution or work around. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that other APIs than the one I used before work fine when the app is deployed in local mode (so Elvis Xia was right). I cannot explain why that specific jQuery Plugin is not working in my context, somehow it causes a script insert unsafe error (it uses plain jQuery html() method though).

Anyways, I deployed the app in local mode (ms-appx:/// prefix), added desired capabilities to the package.windows10.appxmanifest (such as internetClient) and it worked out fine for me now when using plain ajax calls for instance.